# How to find the vector element that indexes the lowest value in an array

Tags: c++, vector

To simplify my issue, let's say I have an array that stores some values:

```
int Costs[5] = {40, 50, 10, 10, 30};
```

and I have a vector which I use to store IDs

```
std::vector<int> id = { 4,0,1 };
```

so that, for example, `Costs [ id [ 0 ] ]` will return the value 30 and so on

I need the INDEX number whose value would point to the lowest value in the Costs array.

In my example the index that I need would be `0` since `Costs[id[0]]` is lower than `Costs[id[1]]` or `Costs[id[2]]`

So if I were to make a function, I would NOT want it to return what `id[0]` holds; I would want it to return the `0`, which is the index / element number.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me code this.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please bare in mind we are not here to write code for you, only to help you with what you struggle.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried, what you can already do and how it is failing

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but I have not been able to come up with any ideas on how to implement this so far. I'm self taught and I was hoping that more experienced / knowledgeable coders could point me in the right direction. I don't expect anyone to code this for me, but if you could push me in the right direction to research and study what I need to know to write such code, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken straight from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

If i understand correctly you want to get the index of the minimal element in an array

This should work both with vectors and arrays alike

```
std::vector<int> v{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9};

// We need to get the min value
std::vector<int>::iterator result = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
// Then we get the index of the value in the array
std::cout << "min element at: " << std::distance(std::begin(v), result);
```

What you can do is first get all the values of Cost array in the position of id values and store them in an temporary std::vector.

According to your code, you can use a iterator over the values contained in ids, inside the loop you use std::vector push_back() function to add the elements in position of Cost[id].

Then apply the above mentioned std::min_element and std::distance to get the index. Note that this will return the index of the id vector, getting the value from there is just a matter of ids[index]

Comment: Thank you very much. I carefully looked at everything in  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ before posting but I didn't know about std::distance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's full working test code. Thank you Jointts for explaining how to do it.

```
int Costs[5] = { 40, 50, 10, 0, 90 };

std::vector<int> id = { 4,1,0 };
std::vector<int> temp;

for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++)
{
    temp.push_back(Costs[id[i]]);
}

std::vector<int>::iterator lowest = std::min_element(std::begin(temp), std::end(temp));
std::cout << "min element at: " << std::distance(std::begin(temp), lowest) << std::endl;
```